# Почему IndexOf() и lastIndexOf() выдают одно и то же значение?

Tags: java, indexof

```
class Prog75 {

    public static void main (String args []) {
    
        String str = "one two three";
        int ch;
        
        ch = str.indexOf("two"); System.out.println (ch);
        
        ch = str.lastIndexOf("two"); System.out.println (ch);
    
    }

}
```

Comment: а почему в этом случае должны быть разные значения?

Comment: как я понимаю, второй метод должен сообщать индекс последнего вхождения подстроки в строку, т.е. не 4 а 6....

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») **должны включать желаемое поведение**, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. **Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны** для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf(int ch)` — возвращает индекс в данной строке первого вхождения указанного символа

`lastIndexOf(int ch)` — возвращает индекс в данной строке последнего вхождения указанного символа

Так как указанный символ в строке встречается лишь один раз, то обе функции возвращают один результат.

Обе функции ищут начальную позицию вхождения слова `two`, а не последнего символа слова `two`

Comment: теперь понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Денис если ответ вам помог - ставьте стрелку вверх. Если правильный - ставьте галку )